# How can I list all Deployments on a specific GKE node pool?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I can't find any examples of how to list all Deployments in all namespaces but only return deployments that are on a specific node pool (the whole pool not just a specific node).

`kubectl get deployments` only includes the node name the Deployment is on not the node pool.

What is the most efficient way to return all Deployments on a specific node pool?

`kubectl` doesn't even provide a way to list node pools- Are node pools too implementation specific for `kubectl` to support this?

Will I really have to do something gross like list all nodes of a pool, loop over each one, list all pods of all deployments, and then match them together?

Deployments can't span node pools right?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong  because I don't work with gke, but in a regular k8s deployment is a description of what should be actually run. So you actually run pods not deployments

If so try using the command

```bash
>> kubectl get pods -o wide
```

You'll see all the pods running along with their nodes
Then use `pipe grep <node name>` and you're done

```bash
>> kubectl get pods -o wide | grep <node you're interested in>
```

Comment: Can a Deployments pods span node pools?

Comment: Basically its up to k8s to decide where to actually deploy the pod. It will allocate pods to nodes according to various factors: available resources, replication policy (how many pods of the application should run), labels (for example ML application might need to be run on a special hardware, like with powerful graphics system)   etc.